# separated unto the gospel of God

Tags: verbs, lexicon

I would like to know what *separated unto* means in this context. This is taken from *Romans 1:1*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He was singled out /set apart / reallocated to [a task other than the one he was doing at the time]. [Here](http://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Romans%201:1) is a list of different English translations.

Comment: And here is another list of translations and editions:  http://www.biblegateway.com/versions/